# Google Map API is not working on release mode

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I am using Google Map in my android. It was working fine. Today I implemented Google Places API, after that when I build release APK, map is not working. I don't know that it is because of Google Places API or because of something else.
I cross verified SHA1 key, keystore file. I am unable to find the issue. I am using these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
```

On opening map, it is showing blank map.

> I am facing it only on release (signed) apk, not on debug apk.
> Screenshot is:
> [image]

Comment: If you have application restrictions on your API key, make sure you include both the debug AND the release fingerprint certificates. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key

Comment: I have added both, unable to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you set your release API key.

> src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Since android generates two different xml files for google maps. One for debug and One for release. You probably have your API key placed on debug only.

Comment: I just used a new key, and it resolved my issue. I was unable to find the issue. BTW Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the google maps api key to the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have added.

Answer (score 0):

if you have restricted your maps api key with SHA1

check if your put release SHA1 not debug one