# Flutter app using Google Maps API is not working on release

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

My flutter app works on emulator but when I make release build and put apk on my phone it gets stuck at this moment:

```
geoloc.Position position = await geoloc.Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: geoloc.LocationAccuracy.high);
    initialPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
```

geoloc is Geolocator:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart' as geoloc;
```

and initialPosition is LatLang variable:

```
late LatLng initialPosition;
```

I tried to add ask for location permission but it was not the case.

I use keystroke generated by this command `keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`
instead of this `keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name`
Cause I forgot the password and I don't know how to reset it.
[image: image showing what google says about this commands]

And also I'm not sure if changing sha1 giving command will help.
According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927864/google-map-api-is-not-working-on-release-mode) I should set release key in src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml but I have nor this directory nor release key.

Comment: Did you signed your release app with debud key?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You dont have to do that. I am just asking if you did that. If so that might be issue. Anyway, which key did you used to sign your release app?

Comment: I used key created on console.cloud.google.com that is restricted using fingerprint created with command for debugging fingerprint. Or are you asking for something else? (Also what means to sign release app?)

Comment: If you have restricted you api from Google Cloud to only work on your app, and you are using debug key on release apk, it might be an issue. By singing release app i mean [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app).

Comment: Good to know, thanks, I'm just learning flutter for few days and want to deploy my prototype app on my phone, not on Google Play Store

Comment: It might be worth filing a support case. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support